# Chrome's remote debugging (USB debugging) not working for Samsung Galaxy S3 running android 4.4.2

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, samsung-mobile

I have a S3 with the developer options and USB debugging enabled on my phone.

I start c:\…\platform-tools>adb start-server

I plug in my phone => see in Device Manager SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface.  Properties for the driver are:
   | Provider:  Samsung Electronics Co
   | Driver Date:  06/10/14
   | Driver Version:  2.11.10.0 |

I launch chrome://inspect/#devices

I see: 
Offline #E218BBA0
Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device.

I NEVER get a RSA key fingerprint panel to pop on my phone where I can grant permission.

The only two options I have for USB computer connection are MTP and PTP.  I have tried both.

Does anyone know what my issue might be (i.e. why my phone does not pop up with the RSA window allowing me to grant permission)?

Thanks,

Brent

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug.

There are a few workarounds but not pretty much nice.

See here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=512150
https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/213

--

I have updated Chrome 15 September 2015 to Version 45.0.2454.93 (64-bit) and It seems that issue is resolved.